# No entra en el condicional if

Tags: javascript, html, web

tengo un pequeño problema.
Estoy construyendo un pequeño reloj pomodoro y no quiere entrar en una condición dentro del bucle while.

```
var cicle = 0;
    while(cicle <= 8){
        if(cicle == 0 || cicle == 2 || cicle == 4 || cicle == 6){
            var counterpomodoro = setInterval(() => {
                if(actividad_timing == 0 && seconds == 0){
                    console.log("jaja acabe el primer ciclo");
                    clearInterval(counterpomodoro);
                    cicle++;
                }
                
                if(seconds == 0){
                    seconds = 60;
                    actividad_timing =  actividad_timing - 1;
                }

                seconds = seconds - 1;
    
                if(seconds < 10){
                    console.log(actividad_timing, ": 0", seconds);
                } else {
                    console.log(actividad_timing, ":", seconds);
                }
    
            }, 50);
        }

        if(cicle == 1 || cicle == 3 || cicle == 5){
            console.log("ciclo 2");
            cicle++;
        }

        console.log("Estoy fuera del bucle -> ", cicle);
        // cicle++;
    }
```

Siempre obtengo como resultado el console.log("Estoy fuera del bucle ->", cicle) a pesar de que las condiciones que están dentro del bucle se cumplen ¿Alguien sabe a que se debe?

Comment: Cuando entras en el primer bucle y usas el setinterval la cola de esa petición va por otro lado, tal como dice su documentación: `El código ejecutado por setInterval se ejecuta en un contexto de ejecución distinto al de la función desde la que fue llamado.`... pero diria que el problema es que mientras intenta ejecutarse en ese otro contexto la CPU va tan disparada con el bucle principal que no lo termina ejecutando nunca. Por otro lado, usas variables que no vemos definidas, y por último, aunque quites el setinterval y entre en el bucle, te has olvidado del cicle=7 y ese provocará lo mismo.

Comment: yo utilizaría do while, en donde primero ejecuta y luego evalúa si seguir o no seguir con el bucle.

Comment: Voy a probar ambas cosas, si tengo algún resultado os aviso.